# python; asyncio async for statement

Tags: python-asyncio

Here is a block of code from: https://github.com/ronf/asyncssh/blob/master/examples/math_server.py#L38

```
async def handle_client(process):
    process.stdout.write('Enter numbers one per line, or EOF when done:\n')

    total = 0

    try:
        async for line in process.stdin:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if line:
                try:
                    total += int(line)
                except ValueError:
                    process.stderr.write('Invalid number: %s\n' % line)
    except asyncssh.BreakReceived:
        pass
```

There is an `async` keyword before the `def`, however there is also one before the `for` loop. In looking at the documentation for asyncio here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html, I do not see any similar uses of this `async` keyword.

So, what does the keyword do in this context?

Comment: This is explained in [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for).

Answer (score 1):

The `async for ... in ...` construct allows you to loop through "Asynchronous iterable" and as stated in comments, detailed explanation is in [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for)

In your example case, the `async for` loop, waits for stdin input, while not blocking other asyncio-loop tasks.
If you would use `for` loop, this would be blocking operation and no other tasks on the loop could be executed unit you've entered input.

---

To get another example, imagine MySQL client fetching x rows from database.
[aio-mysql example](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql/blob/master/examples/example_simple_sa.py#L30)

```
async for row in conn.execute("SELECT * FROM table;"):
    print(row)
```

This fetches single row, and it isn't blocking the execution of other tasks on the asyncio-loop, while waiting for IO operations (mysql query).

Then you do something with the row data you've obtained.

Comment: It might make sense to clarify that in "loop tasks" *loop* refer to the asyncio event loop, not the `async for` loop. Contrary to expectations of many beginners, an `async for` loop is still completely sequential - as sequential as, say, a `while` loop containing `await`s - it just allows other tasks to run (as stated in the answer).

Comment: Thanks for the notice of the asyncio-loop. Feel free to edit the answer :)

Comment: object type you iterate must have `__anext__` magical method defined